# Number of current page doesnt change in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pagination, use-effect

I am using react-paginate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate) to make pagination for my app. Everything is fine but I cannot increase the current number of the page. So for this here is my parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Product from "../components/sub-components/Product";
import SimpleBox from "../components/sub-components/SimpleBox";
import BoxWithSearch from "../components/sub-components/BoxWithSearch";
import LoadingBox from "../components/sub-components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/sub-components/MessageBox";
import Cart from "../components/sub-components/Cart";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageCount, setpageCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(currentPage));
    console.log(currentPage);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handlePageClick = (data) => {
    setCurrentPage(data.selected + 1);
    // scroll to the top
    //window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h2 className="title">Products</h2>
          <div className="product-type-filter">
            <button>Mug</button>
            <button className="clicked">Shirt</button>
          </div>
          <div className="products">
            <div className="row">
              <div>
                {loading ? (
                  <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
                ) : error ? (
                  <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
                ) : (
                  <div className="row center">
                    {products.map((product) => (
                      <Product key={product.added} product={product}></Product>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ReactPaginate
            previousLabel={"Prev"}
            nextLabel={"Next"}
            pageCount={40}
            marginPagesDisplayed={4}
            pageRangeDisplayed={1}
            onPageChange={handlePageClick}
            containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center"}
            pageClassName={"page-item"}
            pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            previousClassName={"page-item"}
            previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            nextClassName={"page-item"}
            nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            breakClassName={"page-item"}
            breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            activeClassName={"active"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my action for fetching the data:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch, currentPage) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/items?_page=${currentPage}&_limit=16`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

But the problem is since the currentPage doesn't change, I cannot go to the other page. Do you have a solution for this?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating the current page and wanting to fetch new data then you might want to add `currentPage` to the `useEffect` dependency array so the *next* current page of products is fetched/listed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(listProducts(currentPage));
  console.log(currentPage);
}, [currentPage, dispatch]);
```

### Update

> When I write `console.log(currentPage)` in action, I am getting this:
> `ƒ getState() { var state = unliftState(liftedStore.getState()); if (state !== undefined) { lastDefinedState = state; } return lastDefinedState; }` How can I pass the `currentpage` number into
> action?

In thunks, the second argument is the `getState` function to be called and get the current redux state. Your `listProducts` action creator is naming the `getState` callback `currentPage`. Also, any arguments being passed to `listProducts` are being ignored (*note the empty arg list in the outer function*).

```
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch, currentPage) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/items?_page=${currentPage}&_limit=16`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

`listProducts` needs to consume the passed `currentPage` argument in the outer functions, and enclose it in function scope.

```
export const listProducts = (currentPage) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/items?_page=${currentPage}&_limit=16`);
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks that changes the current page. But in my action, it doesnt do anything... Can you help me with this also? When I write console.log(currentPage) in action, I am getting this: ƒ getState() {
    var state = unliftState(liftedStore.getState());
    if (state !== undefined) {
      lastDefinedState = state;
    }
    return lastDefinedState;
  } How can I pass the currentpage number into action?

Comment: @magicbean Sure. It seems your `listProducts` action creator was a little malformed. I updated my answer.